# Trying to find transistor needed for laser security alarm

Tags: transistors, batteries, photoresistor, laser-diode

so I'm building a laser security alarm circuit for a class project and I need a transistor, but I'm having difficulty figuring out what type to get to allow the circuit to switch ON/OFF once light is present/not present.

Here is the design i have for the circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdPoQq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here are the specs for parts of the circuit:

1.LDR - GM5539

Max voltage - 150V DC

Max Wattage - 100mW

Light Resistance - 50-100 kOhms

Dark Resistance - 5mOhms

[image]

2. Laser Diode:
   5V, 20mA, 5mW
3. 9V power source

Hope to get an answer soon...Thanks.

Comment: I can't make out the circuit in your photo.  Try using the schematic editor built into the message editor - hit control-M while editing your message to access it.  Otherwise, re-draw your circuit on plain (unlined) paper, and try to take a photo with good contrast.

Comment: i guess...difference is the current isnt amplified

Comment: You should probably plan some hysteresis in the circuit. That's at least two BJTs already. And given the rather high impedance of this device, the resistor values are going to be "highish." What's the drive requirements for the buzzer? Is that a typical 9 V battery whose voltage droops down to as low as 7 V or even less, before it expires?

Answer (score 1):

If your LDR has an 'ON' resistance of 100 kOhms, that means the most current it can shunt away from the base of your transistor is say 0.4V/100k = 4 uA. So, the converse of this is that when the LDR is 'OFF', you only have a 4 uA base drive (if it were more it would overdrive the LDR and switch on the npn all the time). Which means if you use a transistor with a \$\beta=200\$ the most current it will sink is 800 uA.

You will want to know what your LED and buzzer operating current is.

Most likely you will want a FET or a darlington with no base-emitter resistor shunts.